# Flutter - Navigator.push value to list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Navigator.push in a widget, that parse a value to a new widget. That is working. In the Stateful widget that I parse the value, I am trying to add the value to a list, but get an error here:

Producerlist.add (producer)

Any idea how to solve this?

**Navigator.push:**

```
void _sendDataToSecondScreen(BuildContext context) {
    String textToSend = textFieldController.text;
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Test2(producer: textToSend,),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Test2.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String producer;
  List<String> Producerlist = [];

  Test2({Key key, @required this.producer}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  List<String> Producerlist = [];
  Producerlist.add (producer)

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test2')),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: Producerlist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: (){},
                title: Text(Producerlist[index]),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you pass `producer` to `Test2State` or (I believe, haven't tried myself but seen something like this) you use `Producerlist.add (widget.producer)`

UPDATE:

As I said, I haven't tried this with `widget.` myself, yet. So, to be on the sure side, try

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String producer;

  Test2({Key key, @required this.producer}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State(producer);
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  _Test2State(this.producer);
  final String producer;
  List<String> Producerlist = [];
  Producerlist.add (producer)
```

Comment: That gives the same error -  The error is "invalid constructor name"

Comment: do you know, exactly where you get the error and what value is causing it (using the debugger). Your code above could not work ad should have thrown a compile error, however, widget.producer should have fixed it.

Comment: Hi, I did change the widget.producer. This is the error:
                                   ^

  ^^^^^^
lib/screens/receipe/test2.dart:18:3: Error: The name of a constructor must match the name of the enclosing class.
  Producerlist.add (widget.producer)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
.
lib/screens/receipe/test2.dart:18:21: Error: Type 'widget.producer' not found.
  Producerlist.add (widget.producer)
                   
lib/screens/receipe/test2.dart:18:21: Error: 'widget.producer' can't be used as a type because 'widget' doesn't refer to an import prefix.
  Producerlist.add (widget.producer)